# To stuck or to be stuck

Tags: grammar

While buying a ticket from one of the main low-fare flight operators in Europe I've encountered a pop-up with this message:

> Select a seat if you don`t want to stuck in the middle row!

**Is this the correct grammar?** I always thought that the correct form is "to be stuck" but it is hard to imagine to me that such a big company would make a grammar error on their website.

Comment: It's definitely an error. Colin Fine is correct. It should be either "to be stuck" or "to get stuck".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's a mistake. Probably simply left out the word "be" or "get".